# RESTAPI: What is a correct response format and status code when a resource exists however is expired?

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

Let's assume we have resource `Employee`.
Employee looks like that (from entity and DB perspective):

```
{
    id: 123,
    name: "John Doe",
    // more props here
    workPermitExpireDateUTC: "1999-06-30 00:00:00"
}
```

when we query the all employees we want to display additional flag `isExpired` calculated on a fly:

`GET: /api/employees`:

```
// HttpStatuCode: 200
[
    {
        id: 123,
        name: "John Doe",
        // more props here
        workPermitExpireDateUTC: "1999-06-30 00:00:00",
        workPermitExpired: true // calculated on a fly, based on system clock
    },
    {
        id: 456,
        name: "George Smith",
        // more props here
        workPermitExpireDateUTC: "2025-06-30 00:00:00",
        workPermitExpired: false // calculated on a fly, based on system clock
    }
]
```

When I query single non-expired employee

`GET /api/employess/456` I expect to get `200 Response` with the employee data - that's obvious.

However, if we consider expired employee, I **do not** want to send all data, as client is not needed to know it. So my thought is to return like this:

`GET: /api/employees/123`:

```
// HttpStatuCode: 200
{
    id: 123,
    workPermitExpired: true,
    errorMessage: "Employee work permit expired"
}
```

but it doesn't feel right, since `200` response should not have different structure depending on resource id.

How about such url `GET: /api/employees/123/non-expired` and return `200` in case non expired, and `410` in case of expired?

Comment: When you say "client is not needed to know it" does you spec consider a request for an expired employee to be an error (i.e. the client shouldn't be requesting it)? If so the client error [410 Gone](https://httpstatuses.com/410) might be the closest option available to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a correct response format and status code when a resource exists however is expired?

An important thing to understand in REST, is that our API is a *facade*, deliberately designed to make our domain look like every other dumb document store on the web, so that all of the general purpose web tools "just work".

Another way of saying the same thing: HTTP is an application in the domain of [transporting documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s).  What we are doing when we build a REST API, is that we are adapting our domain protocols to a language of exchanging documents with the client.

Status codes and headers belong to the transport-documents-over-a-network domain.

```
GET: /api/employees/123
```

The correct response to this largely depends on whether we have a current representation of this resource (which is a concern of the transport documents domain).  The *semantics* of that representation in *our* domain really don't enter into it.

If we have a current representation of the resource, then this is *fine*

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id": 123,
    "workPermitExpired": true,
    "errorMessage": "Employee work permit expired"
}
```

When we cannot satisfy the request to provide a current resource, then we will normally use a status code that indicates to general purpose components that the response body describes an error condition, rather than a representation of the resource.

```
404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json

{ "error": "Who is 123?" }
```

> it doesn't feel right, since 200 response should not have different structure depending on resource id.

Right.  The way that this usually translates is to define your schema more carefully.  If you are expecting to turn some fields on and off in the representation, then your schema definition needs to describe those fields as optional.  For example, we might describe an "active permit" schema and an "expired permit" schema (under a different key) with the constraint that the client should expect one or the other, but not both.

Another possibility is to use different content types for different representations.  [RFC 6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838) is where you look for details, but the rough outline is that we would define two different schema, and then assign to each schema a distinct content type

- application/prs.maciej-active-permit+json
- application/prs.maciej-expired-permit+json

`application/+json` tells general purpose consumers that the representations are "just" json docments, but consumers that are familiar with your specific media types will have more specific understanding to work with.

[RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) is a standardized demonstration of this approach, where specific semantics for field names are encoded into the json document, and the media type `application/problem+json` tells general-purpose components what is really going on.

You see a similar idea in [application/merge-patch+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386) and [application/json-patch+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, an expired employee is not the same resource type as an employee, e.g.

```
class ExpiredEmployee extends Employee
```

so `200` would be appropriate as you're not returning an `Employee`. You're returning an `ExpiredEmployee`.

If a client is looking for employees presumably they don't care about expired ones, as they're not technically employees? So the main url would be:

`GET /api/employess/456` for un-expired employees

You could think along business lines to design the URLs. Why would anyone want to find expired employees? Do they need to be unexpired? If they're expired why are they still considered employees? If the main line of business for clients is working with employees, it would seem appropriate to have a separate resource endpoint for expired employees as perhaps a separate business process will work them.

If a client isn't expecting an employee to be expired, the returned object may confuse them. Perhaps a separate line of business endpoint would suit expired employees:

`GET /api/employess/expired/456` for expired employees

as presumably whatever is looking for `456` already knows they're expired and wants to change their status?

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion only leads to [typed resources meaningful to clients](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) that introduce a strong coupling between clients and server which is just the opposite of what the REST architecture aims for. The problem here is, that you consider resources as Java or C/C++ objects on the server side that you can act certain business methods upon(=RPC) when in reality they should behave like arbitrary documents (i.e. HTML pages) that you just put up on a server for later usage.

Comment: "Technically, an expired employee is not the same resource type as an employee" - I don't agree. In my system it is always a type of Employee. The entity DOES NOT change it's type during the passage of time.